# Regex and Mask patterns for capital letters and numbers

Tags: regex, devexpress, masking

- **Number or Capital in any order * 10**

Regex for capital letters and numbers:

```
 ^[A-Z0-9]{10}$
```

Explanation:

```
^        : Start anchor
[A-Z0-9] : Char class to match any one of the uppercase letter or digit
{10}     : Quantifier for previous sub-regex 
$        : End anchor
```

Any other suggestions for regex?
And how can I limit the max length of the input?

And what is the Mask pattern for this?
I can't just choose RegEx and use the above pattern for the Edit mask. It seems like the mask automatically inputs and counts **^** , __ , and **&** as a character.

[image]

- I tried `[A-Z0-9]+` and it seems to work, but its max length is 8 characters. I can't seem to increase the max length of the mask.

Comment: Do you see you made a typo? It must be `$` at the end, not `&`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, thanks for clarifying, but it's still the same outcome

Comment: It seems the matches are anchored by default and that means all you need is `[A-Z0-9]{10}`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, that works, but `{10}` seems like doesn't work.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1501/controls-and-libraries/editors-and-simple-controls/common-editor-features-and-concepts/masks/mask-type-extended-regular-expressions#quantifiers) says `{10}` limiting quantifiers are supported.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it seems like I have misunderstood `{10}`.  Isn't that for limiting the max length? For ex. if I use `{0,10}`, it means that I can input min 0 and max 10 characters?

Comment: Yes, `{0,10}` means zero, one ... or ten repetitions of the quantified pattern. So, does `[A-Z0-9]{0,10}` work as intended?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew nope, I've already tried that =_=

Answer (score 0):

Check if it set to *extended* regex (see doc link above).  {} afaik, is not supported typically in non-extended regex.